# How to create skin for libgdx project?

Tags: libgdx, skin

I looked at the default skin files from the test project.
I don't understand why uiskin.png has a font images inside it.
also the uiskin.atlas file contains split field that I don't understand why do I need it and how to use it.

Where can I find a guide to all of the things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably a good starting point to read the [Skin wiki article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin).

For more information there is the [Skin API documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Skin.html) and the [`Skin`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Skin.java) and [`SkinLoader`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/SkinLoader.java) source code.

A good starting point for a completely new skin might also be the [raw default skin](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets-raw/skin) which you can find in the libgdx test assets. This can be packed via `TexturePacker`, because skins will only work with a texture atlas.

For a UI to easily create a `Skin`, someone has recently created an editor for that: [gdx-skineditor](https://github.com/cobolfoo/gdx-skineditor).

Comment: I saw all of this and still didn't get many stuff.
The skineditor collapse on export so I can't save the skin I create.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `noone` answer, you should know that there is a `Scene2D` extension that adds a new default skin and extra widgets: [VisUI](https://github.com/kotcrab/vis-editor/wiki/VisUI). It uses [USL](https://github.com/kotcrab/vis-editor/wiki/USL) internally, which makes it easier to write `Skin` files than with "pure" JSON.

Answer (score 0):

the fonts image you see is for the following bitmap font declared in the [uiskin.json](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json):

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
```

if the uiskin.atlas would not contain a default.png image for the font, libdgx would have trouble rendering the font.

Comment: I changed this font file and now I see strange things inside the label, like the .fnt is not suitable for the .png

Comment: What did you change? What did you expect? Didn't you just want to know why there is a font packed in the skin's texture atlas?